# Using an object constructor to create a section of html

Tags: javascript, html, constructor

I'm creating a webpage where the user contributes towards a section of a report. When a button is clicked, a new subsection is added to the report. The section will contain one heading element, one paragraph element, and any number of figure elements.

I'm using an object constructor to create an object that contains all these elements. It looks like this (simplified):

```
function Subsection() {
  this.divSubsection = document.createElement("div");
  this.heading = document.createElement("h2");
  this.bodyText = document.createElement("p");
  this.figures = [];

  this.divSubsection.appendChild(this.heading);
  this.divSubsection.appendChild(this.bodyText);
}
```

Here I create three elements (a div, h2 and p) as properties of the subsection object. I then make the latter two elements children of the former.

I will now get an object where the h2 and p elements are available under their own properties and also by traversing the elements in the divSubsection property. Do the properties just hold references to the element objects, or are they duplicated in memory? Is there anything wrong with this method?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated in memory"? Every time you create a new instance of that function new elements are created, and those elements, and the instance, is stored in memory. There's nothing wrong with it, but just a regular function that returns the element will do the same job.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem you faced here.

Comment: I mean that when this object constructor function is used to create a new object, the h2 element, for instance, gets stored under both the `heading` property **and** the `divSubsection` property. Being new to objects I wondered if this would create problems, as I've not seen this done before.  Do the properties of my new object contain separate copies of h2, or both contain a reference to h2? Playing around with it suggests the latter, but I was looking for reassurance.